# Error when trying to upload a file in Angular (Content-Disposition)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to upload a File with angular, when I do the petition it occours an error. It says Request has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-disposition is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

This is my code:

```
  postXml(serviceName: string, data:any = {}){
    const url = environment.apiUrl + "/" + serviceName;
    let token = this.storageService.getWithoutAsync(AuthConstants.AUTH);
    const header = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
      'Authorization': `${token}`,
      'Content-Disposition':"attachment; filename='file.xls'"
    });
    return this.http.post(url, data, { headers: header})
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error its because your are doing a HttpRequest to a different domain than your page is on. So the browser is blocking it as it usually allows a request in the same origin for security reasons. You need to allow from the API that multiple domains can call this API. [Here](https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/) you can find some help

You can check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to better understanding